# Change the navbar color in mobile mode on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, sidebar

I have a problem if my navbar on the website looks normal but if it is set to mobile display then the dropdown disappears, it might be caused when in transparent mobile mode, I use bootstrap and I want to change the transparent color to be the same as the navbar color, following the display if in mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb49d.png)

Answer (score 0):

The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices. you can simply define bootstrap navbar class color here.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 640px) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
/* Styles */
}
```